# console.log(document.head) results alternate with each refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I just discovered something that really puzzled me:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.head);
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Every time I refresh this page in Safari and Chrome, the console output alternates between a JavaScript "HTMLHeadElement" and the HTML itself.

Would anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: For the record, there is a webkit bug on this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115800

Answer (score 2):

I tried the experiment in Chrome and got the same results.  My guess is some sort of parsing race condition in the webkit implementation.

When I modified the code to not run the code right away, I then could get consistent results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(document.head) } , 0);
</script>
```

The console would show the HTML with the expand/collapse triangle, so probably as an object.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

And if I added `.outerHTML`, I would get consistent results there as well, logging the HTML as a string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.head.outerHTML);
</script>
```

Lastly, adding a `.toString()` would consistently log `[object HTMLHeadElement]`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.head.toString());
</script>
```